# How to update a document field in mongoDB using mongoose findOneAndUpdate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a field in a mongodb document by `findOneAndUpdate` method of mongoose. I am have tried few answers from similar questions in stack overflow. But I am still facing the issue.

Here is my model schema

```
const auth = {
    trainerID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    otp: String,
    isVerified: Boolean,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
};
```

And I am making a `POST/PATCH`api call to verify the OTP and update the `isVerified` field to true, by default the field is set to `false`.

Here is my code:

```
//Validate the otp
if (validTrainer.otp === req.body.otp ) {
        console.log(`send otp: ${req.body.otp}`);
        console.log(`original otp:${validTrainer.otp}`);
        await TrainerAuth.findOneAndUpdate({ trainerID: req.body.trainerID }, { new: true }, { $set: { isVerified: true } }, (err, newAuth) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(newAuth);
                res.send({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    message: `Phone number is verified.`
                })
            }
        })
    } else {
        res.send({
                    statusCode: 401,
                    message: `Wrong OTP. Try again.`
                })
    }
```

Right now I am getting the expected response

```
{
  statusCode: 200,
  message: `Phone number is verified.`
}
```

But the field is not being updated.

Comment: you have mismatched arguments, it should be  `{ trainerID: req.body.trainerID }, { $set: { isVerified: true } }, { new: true }` first is query/filter second is your update part, third is other options.

Comment: @turivishal thanks. that solve my issue. chilly, tried everything expect this :P

Answer (score 1):

please the following code:

```
//Validate the otp
if (validTrainer.otp === req.body.otp ) {
  console.log(`send otp: ${req.body.otp}`);
  console.log(`original otp:${validTrainer.otp}`);
  await TrainerAuth.findOneAndUpdate({ trainerID: req.body.trainerID }, { isVerified: true }, { new: true }, (err, newAuth) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          console.log(newAuth);
          res.send({
              statusCode: 200,
              message: `Phone number is verified.`
          })
      }
  })
} else {
  res.send({
              statusCode: 401,
              message: `Wrong OTP. Try again.`
          })
}
```